# Microchip RN2903: TX/RX distance with internal antenna

Tags: networking, lora, lorawan

My question is about the maximum transmission distance achieved with the Microchip SoC RN2903, only using its **internal antenna**.

I've been doing field tests in urban environments, with this module and a Kerlink gateway Wirnet Station (and The Things Network). I have only been able to test distances of up to 1 km and I would like to know your experiences and field measurements with this SoC LoRaWAN.

Answer (score 1):

The distance for uplink messages mainly depends on the gateway.
You cannot do too much on the device's side since it usually has ~0dBi antenna and its radiated power is limited by the regulator to ~16dBm.
On the gateway you can apply the following techniques:

- use a high gain antenna e.g.: 8+dBi
- use antenna diversity (2 antennas connected on the same gateway)
- install your antenna as high as possible
- if you install your gateway close to other transmitting devices, e.g.: 3g base stations wifi routers etc, you may apply cavity filters.
  If you apply all these techniques, you can reach 15+km distance (assuming you have line of sight)